# Does forcing a data line to a higher power make it more resistant to interference?

Tags: power, data, transmission-line, hdmi

A device I'm working on as a hobby project requires me to transmit a HDMI signal over cat5. The TMDS lines in HDMI are balanced but in order for me to continue transmitting the DDC signal with the TMDS lines (which are needed for the EDID and HDCP) I would need to remove the out of phase line on the four TMDS signals in order to fit all the lines in the 8 wire cat 5. I can simply reconstruct the balanced pair on the other end using a redriver or inverter or something of the sort. My question is, without that balanced line, how high of an error rate can I expect on a 1.65 ghz TMDS signal and if I force the signal into a wider power range can I mitigate the loss?

Comment: If you try to send different unbalanced signals over the two wires of a twisted pair at 1.6 GHz, you are asking for trouble.

Comment: Would it be possible to use 2 Cat5 cables instead of just one?

Comment: What length? How were you planning to increase the signal power? This whole thing feels very unlikely to work.

Comment: If bit errors are being caused by inter-symbol interference, boosting the transmission power is useless. If bit errors are being caused by external interference, boosting transmission power may help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using HDbaseT? I don't know if the chip-set is available for hobbiest though you may have to get one that is ready made.

Used it for an install job and it worked like a charm, as a bonus it carry's Ethernet and power as well plus a IR backhall!